# overriding data-confirm values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the value of data-confirm attribute on a button (submit) based on user's choices on a form.   I put the following on the change function of a dropdown list:

```
...
    if($("#"+select_name).val() == "abc")
     {
         $(".variable_button").attr("data-confirm","abc is good choice!");

     } else
     {
         $(".variable_button").attr("data-confirm","abc would have been great but this is fine too...");
     }
...
```

The problem I am facing is that apparently data-confirm cannot be changed once it is assigned a non-empty string.  I have it set to "" in the server code.  And, it changes to one of the two messages shown above when the user first makes a selection on the dropdownlist.  But if the user changes the selection one more time, the data-confirm message does not change.  Is this per design or am I missing something?

Comment: The `data-confirm` attributes are just custom `data-` attributes that you're using to store the message, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `.attr()`, use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data):

```
var newData = ($("#"+select_name).val() == "abc")
    ? "abc is good choice!"
    : "abc would have been great but this is fine too...";

$(".variable_button").data("confirm", newData);
```

Comment: Thanks Matt!  Josh - I am not sure why .attr() did not work.  But I tried it both ways and the .data() method worked without any issues.  With the .attr() method I was only able to change the value from empty string to something (once) and no further changes worked.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does allow you to update a `data-` attribute with the `.attr()` method, so something else is breaking.

Here's a working example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshearl/D6BpW/)):

```
var counter = 1;

$('#click').click(function() {
    button = $('#click');
    console.log(button.attr('data-confirm'));
    button.attr('data-confirm', 'this is test ' + counter);
    console.log(button.attr('data-confirm'));
    counter++;
});
```

Can you try to repo the issue in a JSFiddle?

On rereading your question, it sounds like an event handler isn't firing the second time the user changes the selection. See if you can set a breakpoint in your event handler to see if it even gets hit.